# Is the distribution of the Pearson correlation symmetric around zero?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $(X_1, Y_1), \ldots, (X_n, Y_n)$ be a sample from a bivariate distribution $\operatorname{Law}(X_1, Y_1)$. It is known that if $\operatorname{Law}(X_1, Y_1)$ is bivariate normal and $\operatorname{Corr}(X_1, Y_1) = 0$ then the density function of the sample Pearson correlation coefficient $\hat{\rho}(X,Y)$ is
$$
f(r) = \frac{(1-r^2)^{\frac{n-4}{2}}}{B(0.5, 0.5(n-2))}, \quad r \in [-1,1]
$$
where
$$
\hat{\rho}(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})(Y_i - \overline{Y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \overline{Y})^2}}.
$$
So in this case the distribution of the sample correlation is symmetric around zero.

Will the symmetric property hold for an arbitrary bivariate distribution with square integrable marginals and zero correlation between components? I know how to prove that even in this arbitrary setting
$$
\hat{\rho} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{d, \mathbb{P}} 0,
$$
so the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\rho}$ is symmetric around zero. What I can't handle is how to prove the property for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thank you in advance.

UPD. More general question: consider the [general correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_correlation#General_correlation_coefficient)
$$
\hat{r}_f(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}) := \frac{\sum_{i,j}c_{i,j}(\mathbf{X})c_{i,j}(\mathbf{Y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}c^2_{i,j}(\mathbf{X})}\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}c^2_{i,j}(\mathbf{Y})}},
$$
where $c_{i,j}(\mathbf{X}) = f(X_i, X_j)$ for some antisymmetric function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. It is easy to derive that for the Pearson correlation coefficient $f(t,s) = t-s$. Is $\hat{r}_f$ symmetric around zero assuming $X_1, Y_1$ is independent?

Comment: My guess is that there is something special about uncorrelated joint normal pairs, because as soon as they are correlated the estimator is biased: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220961/is-the-sample-correlation-coefficient-an-unbiased-estimator-of-the-population-co

Comment: Since $\hat{\rho}$ is a function of the sample mean of $(X, Y, X^2, Y^2, XY)$ and the sample mean has asymptotically joint multivariate normal distribution by the central limit theorem, you can use the delta method to get that the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\rho} - \rho)$ is normal with mean $0$. So if $\rho$ is $0$, you at least have that $\sqrt{n}\hat{\rho}$ converges to a $N(0, V)$ variable, which is symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

Empirically, it doesn't seem to be the case. Here is the distribution of $\hat\rho(X,Y)$ where $X_i, Y_i\sim\text{Exponential}(1)$ i.i.d., $i=1,\dots,10$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, the distribution of $\hat{\rho}$ need not be symmetric, even for $n = 1$. Here if $E(X) = E(Y) = 0$, then $\hat{\rho} = \frac{X}{|X|}\frac{Y}{|Y|}$, which will have positive mean if you take $X$ and $Y$ to have the same distribution and $E(X / |X| > 0)$. For example, $P(X = 1) = 2/3, P(X = -2) = 1/3$.

Comment: The estimator is not well-defined for $n=1$ as you get $0/0$. The means of $X$ and $Y$ are also unknown in this question, so you wouldn't be able to replace $\overline{X}$ with $E(X)$